# template C++ class with default template template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, default

I have a generic class template MyClass and want specialization impl according to enType value. Question is what's the right syntax in order to use ServiceCreate based on enType value also?

```
template <enum enType, typename ServiceCreator = CServiceFactory<enum enType>>
class MyClass 
{
public:
    MyClass(const Configuration& cfg) {}
public:
    bool init()  { return false; }
    bool start()  { throwException(); }
    void stop()  { throwException(); }
private:
    void throwException() const { THROW(Exception, "invalid/unsupported mode"); }
};

// I need a specialization impl, so which one of the following 3 possible ways? or all are wrong?
template <typename ServiceCreator>
class MyClass<enType::eCase1> 
{
public:
    MyClass(const CConfiguration& cfg) {
        ServiceCreator(cfg); // it will create something for me by using CServiceFactory<eCase1>
    }
};

template <>
class MyClass<enType::eCase1> 
{
public:
    MyClass(const CConfiguration& cfg) {
        ServiceCreator(cfg); // it will create something for me by using CServiceFactory<eCase1>
    }
};

template <>
class MyClass<enType::eCase1, ServiceCreator<enType::eCase1> 
{
public:
    MyClass(const CConfiguration& cfg) {
        ServiceCreator(cfg); // it will create something for me by using CServiceFactory<eCase1>
    }
};
```

Comment: where is that ans?

Comment: hope I can tick it soon.